# Can i use b2MouseJoint on a kinematic body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I can't find any documentation on the b2MouseJoint..
Is it only for dynamic bodies? Or can i use it on kinematic?
And if not, how else can i move kinematic other than applying a force?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of kinematic bodies as having an infinite mass, so they do not respond to forces or impulses. Usually the whole point of using them is because they do not get pushed or bumped around by other things in the world, so a mouse joint will have no effect.

You can move them with SetLinearVelocity and SetAngularVelocity.

Comment: Okay but i need them to be dragged by user and not affected by gravity, so i thought kinematic was the way to go.

Comment: I see. I guess you would have to manually set the velocity so that the body moves to the right place.

Comment: I have multiple kinematic bodies that user can drag, so its all pretty dynamic. I was thinking to set the velocity, store the drag location in the body user data, run a loop in update method to retrieve location from user data and stop velocity if they have reached or exceeded that location. What do you think? How can i store & retrieve CGPoint in userdata?

Comment: I would probably store the location of the start point of the touch in a global or class variable, along with the position of the body when the touch began. You could look at the current position of the touch to know how far the touch has moved, and therefore where the body should be relative to where it started. Then you can set an appropriate velocity to make it move there.

Comment: You can make the body a dynamic body, and have it unaffected by gravity. According to the manual, use `bodyDef.gravityScale = 0.0f;` and it will not be affected by the world gravity.